# PostgreSQL on production and MySQL local in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, heroku, laravel

I'm using Heroku for a Laravel application, and has used the following guide to set up PostgreSQL on Heroku:

http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-on-heroku-using-a-postgresql-database

However, using MySQL locally won't work when using composer or artisan:

`vagrant@precise64:~/site$ php artisan migrate {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: host","file":"\/var\/www\/photo backend\/app\/config\/database.php","line":7}}vagrant@precise64:~/site$`

Is there a way to use MySQL locally and PostgreSQL on development?

Comment: It was a pain to set up with Vagrant. If you have a quick guide, I would set it up locally as well.

Comment: If you are using Vagrant for Laravel, you should be using Homestead, it comes with everything set, incuding PostgreSQL: http://laravel.com/docs/homestead